# Hibernate Batch Insert in Informix database (Getting sql log trace)

Tags: hibernate, informix

I am trying to batch insert and update using hibernate in informix database.
But I am not able to find whether the inserts are actually batched or not. Is there any property that we need to set to get logs of the sql statements. 
eg: In mysql, we use profileSQL=true
I tried setting SQLIDEBUG=filePath in the connection URL but the file was non-readable. Is there any other way to get the sql logs so that I can verify if the inserts and updates are batched.

Also, what informix driver version would batch insert and update properly. In MySql I observed that MySql connector 5.1.28 was not batching properly while 5.1.18 was batching properly. Is there any similar issue with informix?

Answer (score 5):

To read (decode) the SQLIDEBUG file you need a tool included in the Informix CSDK package.
On Windows is named 'sqliprt.exe', on Linux/Unix/everythingelse is 'sqliprint'
You may already have it in the IDS server bin directory as CSDK is usually installed with the engine.

A quick example:

```
D:\Infx\work\Java>javac batchdec.java

D:\Infx\work\Java>del sqlitra*

D:\Infx\work\Java>java batchdec
        257     0.000
        258     0.000
        259     0.000
        260     0.000



D:\Infx\work\Java>which sqliprt
D:\infx\csdk410tc4\bin/sqliprt.exe

D:\Infx\work\Java>sqliprt -notimestamp -tuple sqlitrace1507202847283.0 > sqlitrace.txt

D:\Infx\work\Java>
```

The 'sqlitrace.txt' should be a plain text file. If you see any SQ_PUT messages like the one below it basically means you are doing a batch update:

```
----- sqlitrace.txt -----
.....
C->S (70)           
    SQ_ID
        1
    SQ_CURNAME
         "_ifxc0000000000001" [18]
    SQ_OPEN
    SQ_PUT
        Size of data row: 7
        # rows..........: 4
================================================================================
HEX DUMP:
       0:  c1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
    0x10:  c1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

================================================================================
    SQ_EOT

S->C (48)           
    SQ_INSERTDONE
        0
    Bigserial:0
    SQ_DONE
        Warning..: 0x10
        # rows...: 4
        rowid....: 261
        serial id: 0
    SQ_COST
        estimated #rows: 1
        estimated I/O..: 2
    SQ_EOT
```

rather than individuals inserts.
Any recent informix driver should work with batch operations. but I suggest to stick to the latest one (4.10.9)

They can be found via Maven or through your IBM download site.

Gradle

```
compile group: 'com.ibm.informix', name: 'jdbc', version: '4.10.9'
```

Maven

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
<artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
<version>4.10.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using jdbc informix driver
What version should I use?
<dependency>
 <groupId>jdbc</groupId>
 <artifactId>ifxjdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: the latest which is 4.10.9, go for that one.